# Is there any way I can implement pull down appbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can anyone suggest to me how can I build a pull-down appbar. I searched the whole net but can't find any idea regarding this. It would be great if anyone could guide or suggest to me to build the appbar.

**Edit:-**
Many developers are saying to use SliverAppBar. SliverAppBar basically collapses the app bar when we scroll up the listview or any other widget, whereas I want an app bar that pulls down i.e when we tap the app bar and scroll it down only the app bar grows on top of the body. So basically when we navigate to the home screen the app bar should look like the second referred image i.e it must be closed. But we can pull down that appbar to view the hidden contents of the appbar. I am attaching an image for reference.
[image]

Comment: I think you are finding of like this,refer this link https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html

Comment: I have made some edits to the post please refer. It will make the question much clear.

Comment: Refer this link, https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2 - it might be solve your issue

Comment: Thanks, I think this plugin might fit, will update you after implementing it.

Comment: The package worked great, really appreciate your solution thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

I Think what you mean what pull down App is an Appbar that expands try.

the silver Appbar
https://youtu.be/mSc7qFzxHDw

Comment: I have made some changes to the post please refer. It will make the question much clear.